# How to retrieve child data in Firebase by using "PUSH" without an any encryption format

Tags: java, javascript, php, android, firebase

I am building a messenger app in android and I am trying to retrieve data from Firebase in my android application. But when I do I get the full tree in my screen. I want to access the child directly. Is there a way to get only the value I want?

```
retr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Attach an listener to read the data at our posts reference
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                totalmsg[0] =snapshot.getValue().toString();
                emultiview.setText(totalmsg[0].toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I want to retrive hello from this in Firebase. The problem i am facing here is the encryption data. Is there any way I can retrieve that? And I am not able to append data without using push(),is there any other alternative to push()?

```
{
  "chat" : {
    "-JZvOzp0L1ccuBt2TVN7" : {
      "author" : "JavaUser21221",
      "message" : "hello "
    },
    "-JZvPneW5et0_EVRvL5g" : {
      "author" : "JavaUser21221",
      "message" : "hai"
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get the child you're looking for by using `ref.child('path/to/child').addValueEventListener(`. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/index.html

Comment: I am sorry but i dont understand what is a 'path to child' is it a url? and whers should implement this code,Is there a way to get the url of the child alone ?....  please help me,i am beginer.

Comment: If you want a better explanation, edit you question to include some information about your data structure. @Ankita gave an example in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
r.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildKey) {

                        Map<String,Object> newPost=(Map<String,Object>)snapshot.getValue();

                        String name1 = String.valueOf(newPost.get("Author"));
                        String message1 = String.valueOf(newPost.get("Title"));


                        System.out.println("Message: " + newPost.get("Author"));
                        System.out.println("Name: " + newPost.get("Title"));

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

suppose you have followig structure in your firebase database :

```
users:{ uid:[userid]
          name:[username]
}
Student:{ rollno:[rollno]
          name:[studendname]
}
```

Then to access the users child you can use the url `ref.child('users/'+userid).addValueEventListener(...`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final answer i founds out

```
ref1.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    // Retrieve new posts as they are added to Firebase
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildKey) {

                        Map<String,Object> newPost=(Map<String,Object>)snapshot.getValue();

                        String name1 = String.valueOf(newPost.get("Name"));
                        String message1 = String.valueOf(newPost.get("Message"));

                        System.out.println("---------------- full data ---------------------");
                        System.out.println("Message: " + newPost.get("Message"));
                        System.out.println("Name: " + newPost.get("Name"));
                        System.out.println("----------------- end of full data --------------------");

                        if(name1.equals("CCCCC"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("---------------- conditioned data ---------------------");
                            System.out.println("Message: " + newPost.get("Message"));
                            System.out.println("Name: " + newPost.get("Name"));
                            System.out.println("----------------- end of conditioned data --------------------");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```